# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in Chrome on OSX Mavericks

Tags: javascript, macos, angularjs, google-chrome

I'm trying to run an angular app using linemanjs in Chrome on a Mac and I'm getting this error

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Here's the kicker, the site runs fine on Chrome on a windows machine.
It also runs fine on Safari on the same machine.

Another thing I tried is to run it on another Mac, in which I got the same results.

Stepping through the code seems to indicate the problem being at line 1338 in the angular.js file:

```
var injector = createInjector(modules);
```

Specifically in the createInjector function - line 3603

```
forEach(loadModules(modulesToLoad), function(fn) { instanceInjector.invoke(fn || noop); });
```

Seems like chrome on a mac is choking on the number of modules we're trying to load.
How do I fix this issue?

I've tried opening chrome via terminal with args, but the problem still persists

```
open -a Google\ Chrome.app --args --js-flags="--stack-trace-limit 999999"
```

Comment: Have to think the issue isn't that you're loading too many modules. More likely something is infinite/recursive looping. Are you sure there isn't anything squirrely with your module definitions?

Comment: If that was the case, it wouldn't load in chrome/ff/ie on windows, or safari on the macs. We only encountered this problem recently when we took on a designer and she tried to load the site on chrome on her mac.

Comment: Well then you must have some heavy duty dependencies. My bet is still that there is something off in your code that is only expressed in Chrome on Mac OS (ie. it is the same software as Windows except it isn't).

Comment: that makes more sense, but the problem is that it works fine in safari on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in a long concatenated set of strings.

var x = 'A'+'A'+ .... +'A';

I found that if you have a large number of 'A' (more than 6285 string literals to be precise) in Chrome for mac, you'll be presented with this exception.

This occurred to me during program evaluation time, so I had no stack trace to help me. It was a very huge JS (65k lines), so it was like finding a needle in a haystack.

Maybe this information helps someone that finds this post.